# discord.js client.guilds returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

`` "Server count:", `${client.guilds} ``
This is returning [Object object] and when I use .length after .guilds it just returns undefined. Can I get some help with this? (and yes i've looked at discord.js.org and .guilds does return the count.)
[issue at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShB1a.png)

Comment: `Discord.Client` returns the class of Client, not an actual client instance. `Client#guilds` returns a *GuildManager* for accessing the guilds, not the actual count as [seen here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). To get the count you must use `client.guilds.cache.size`

Comment: I'm well aware but in the documentation `Discord.Client.guilds` is supposed to return the guild count of the current client.

Comment: Please check the current documentation. client.guilds returns an instance of GuildManager. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds

Comment: The definition next to that says "All of the guilds the client is currently handling, mapped by their ids - as long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every guild the bot is a member of". I'm sorry if I am confused by this but it seems that it returns the guilds that it is "handling".

Comment: Yes, a *Collection [Map]* of guilds. It's an iterator containing all the guilds, similar to an object. But this will not resolve into a raw number. You must use `cache.size`.

Comment: Look at what GuildManager actually is. It contains a copy of the client and .cache, which is a collection containing the data you are actually looking for here.

Comment: Alright thank you I believe I attempted that but I may have approached it wrong. I will attempt again.

Answer (score 0):

Use Discord.Client.guilds.cache.size
(thanks for the answer [Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931/elitezen) and [Private_GER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8212738/private-ger))